# How to use ImageResizer on a base64 image string

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I am trying to use ImageResizer in my MVC ASP.NET application, but I am not using traditional image sources such as a png. I have the images saved as base64 strings. How would I go about using ImageResizer on a base64 image string.

My attempt:

```
<img src="@item.ImageString?width=150" />
```

However with this method, the image is not found for obvious reasons.

Is there any way to use ImageResizer with a base64 image string or is there a way to convert a base64 image string back to a png?

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the string back into a byte array via `Convert.FromBase64String()`, you can pass those bytes to ImageResizer as the `source` object.